# Changing file names and organising

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good afternoon,

I am attempting to write a programme that renames all files in a folder and adds a prefix to them, however when the programme adds the prefix and changes the name it muddles the order and i need to to organise it in the date and time order of the file name

```
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path

files = Path("D:/")
count = 1
for file in files.iterdir():
    if file.is_file() and file.suffix == '.txt':
        directory = file.parent
        extension = file.suffix

        old_name = file.stem
        old_name, old_date, old_time = old_name.split(' ')

        old_date = datetime.strptime(old_date, '%d%m%y')
        date = datetime.strftime(old_date, '%d.%m.%y')

        new_prefix = '(AY5.{}) '.format(count)
        new_name = f'{new_prefix} {date} {old_time}{extension}'


        new_path = files.joinpath('Renamed files')

        if not new_path.exists():
            new_path.mkdir()

        new_file_path = new_path.joinpath(new_name)

        file.replace(new_file_path)
        count += 1


new_files_dir = Path("D:/Renamed files")
with open('file names.txt', 'w+') as f:
    for new_files in new_files_dir.iterdir():
        if new_files.is_file() and new_files.suffix == '.txt':
            f.write(new_files.stem + '\n')

f.close()
```

This is my code, can someone point me in the right direction please

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question (maybe an example would help). If I understand correctly, your problem is that `file names.txt` is unsorted. That's because `iterdir()` [doesn't sort the files](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir). You could first add all files to a list and sort that, before writing them to a file.

Comment: So file name is currently something like 220322 voicemail 0560

Comment: date, name, time. I have made it so it read date time filename - 22.03.22 050 voicemail but i need it to sort it in date and time but the programme is muddling them all up. so i have numerous 22.03.22 files and 23.03.22 files but they all get jumbled

Comment: Does it work if you replace the last `for` loop with `f.write('\n'.join(sorted([n.stem for n in new_files_dir.iterdir() if n.is_file() and n.suffix == '.txt'])))`?

Comment: @jfschaefer just tried, did not work, it appears to have continued to loop through the list and created duplicate of the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you need to sort the files already in the first iteration, otherwise n in AY5.{n} will be wrong.
Full example:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import re

PATH = Path.home() / 'file-rename'  # replace with your path


def generate_test_files():
    orig_files = [
        'a-name 220301 0740.txt',
        'x-name 220302 0120.txt',
        'not txt',
        'c-name 220303 0340.txt',
        'a-name 220301 0510.txt',
        'b-name 220301 0510.txt',
        'c-name 220301 0510.txt',
        'e-name 220301 0510.txt',
        'y-name 220301 0510.txt',
        'f-name 220301 0510.txt',
        'g-name 220301 0510.txt',
        'z-name 220301 0510.txt',
    ]
    for name in orig_files:
        f = PATH / name
        f.write_text("")


def get_date(f: Path):
    file_name = f.stem
    old_name, old_date, old_time = file_name.split(' ')

    return datetime.strptime(f'{old_date} {old_time}', '%d%m%y %H%M')


def get_number(f: Path):
    file_name = f.stem
    m = re.search(r'\(AY5\.(\d+)\)', file_name)

    return int(m.groups()[0])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # generate_test_files()  # for testing only

    files = PATH
    # *.txt files need to be sorted according to date and time
    for count, file in enumerate(sorted(files.glob('*.txt'), key=get_date)):
        directory = file.parent
        extension = file.suffix

        old_name = file.stem
        old_name, old_date, old_time = old_name.split(' ')

        old_date = datetime.strptime(old_date, '%d%m%y')
        date = datetime.strftime(old_date, '%d.%m.%y')

        new_prefix = '(AY5.{}) '.format(count + 1)  # with enumerate() goes from 0
        new_name = f'{new_prefix} {date} {old_time}{extension}'

        new_path = files.joinpath('Renamed files')

        if not new_path.exists():
            new_path.mkdir()

        new_file_path = new_path.joinpath(new_name)

        file.replace(new_file_path)

    new_files_dir = PATH / 'Renamed files'
    with open('file names.txt', 'w+') as f:
        # needs to be sorted again, but this time according to the number
        for new_files in sorted(new_files_dir.iterdir(), key=get_number):
            f.write(new_files.stem + '\n')
```